# ionic front camera does not open

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

Using ionic plugin "name": "cordova-plugin-camera","version": "2.2.0". I am not getting front facing camera but opens back facing camera, also tried with  cameraDirection : 1 as described on the [link](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/) but it results in back facing camera. i have tested on Android 4.4 and 5.1
is there any way to get front facing camera open by switching or any other way or any fix?

Also debugged straight inside camera plugin code as on the [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/www/Camera.js) here i also got cameraDirection = 1 which is for front facing camera, but unable to resolve the problem.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  //camera settings
  $rootScope.options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 100,
    targetHeight: 100,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation:true,
    cameraDirection : Camera.Direction.FRONT
  };
  $cordovaCamera.getPicture($rootScope.options).then(function cameraSuccess(imageData) {
    $rootScope.imageData = imageData;
  },function cameraError(err){
    console.log(err);
    $rootScope.imageData = '';
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_Camera.Direction) you have to pass number in `cameraDirection`

So in your code write as follow:

```
 $rootScope.options = {
   quality: 50,
   destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
   sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
   encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
   targetWidth: 100,
   targetHeight: 100,
   popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
   saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
   correctOrientation:true,
   cameraDirection : 1 // 0 means BACK, 1 means FRONT
 };
```

Comment: I have tried with this as well, as i maintained in my question, but it results back facing camera.